# mobile redirect to regular site - trouble with javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I'm having issues with redirecting mobile users to the regular site if they click the redirect link; when the link is clicked, they are still directed to the mobile site.

I'm using the following bit of javascript:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    c_name = c_name.toLowerCase();
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    c_name = c_name.toLowerCase();
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            //alert("x = " + x);
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function getQuerystring(key, default_) {
    key = key.toLowerCase();
    //alert("key : " + key);
    //alert("default_ : " + default_);
    if (default_ == null) default_ = "";
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href.toLowerCase());
    if (qs == null) {
        //alert("default_ : " + default_);
        return default_;
    } else {
        //alert("qs[1] : " + qs[1]);
        return qs[1];
    }
}

function detectMobileAndRedirect(a, b) {
    // alert(location.href);
    if (/android|webOS|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|elaine|hiptop|ip(hone|od)|kindle|midp|mmp|mobile|o2|opera mini|palm( os)?|pda|plucker|pocket|psp|smartphone|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce; (iemobile|ppc)|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-)|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {
        if (/ipad/i.test(a)) {
            return false;
        }
        location.href = b;
    }
}

function removeQueryString(url) {
    return url.split("?")[0];
}
var FullSiteCookie = getCookie("viewFullSite");
var viewFullSite = getQuerystring("viewFullSite");
var renderFullSite = new Boolean();
renderFullSite = false;
if (FullSiteCookie != null && FullSiteCookie != "") {
    if (FullSiteCookie.toLowerCase() == "true") {
        if (viewFullSite.toLowerCase() == "false") {
            setCookie("viewFullSite", false, 1);
        } else {
            renderFullSite = true;
            //alert("Set 11");
        }
    } else {
        if (viewFullSite != null && viewFullSite != "") {
            if (viewFullSite.toLowerCase() == "true") {
                renderFullSite = true;
                //alert("Set 2");
                setCookie("viewFullSite", true, 1);
            } else {
                if (viewFullSite.toLowerCase() == "false") {
                    setCookie("viewFullSite", false, 1);
                }
                renderFullSite = false;
                //alert("Set 3");
            }
        } else {
            renderFullSite = false;
            //alert("Set 4");
        }
    }
} else {
    viewFullSite = getQuerystring("viewFullSite");
    //alert("viewFullSite 1 : " + viewFullSite);
    if (viewFullSite != null && viewFullSite != "") {
        if (viewFullSite.toLowerCase() == "true") {
            renderFullSite = true;
            //alert("Set 5");
            setCookie("viewFullSite", true, 1);
        } else {
            renderFullSite = false;
            //alert("Set 6");
        }
    } else {
        renderFullSite = false;
        //alert("Set 7");
    }
}
//alert("renderFullSite : " + renderFullSite);
if (!renderFullSite) {
    //alert("location href before: " + location.href);
    var mobilesite = "http://parlourdc.mobi";
    var locationhref = removeQueryString(location.href);
    //alert("location href after: " + locationhref);
    if (locationhref == "http://parlourdc.com") {
        mobilesite = "http://parlourdc.mobi/index.php";
    }
    detectMobileAndRedirect(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, mobilesite);
}

function BookMark() {
    $('#BookmarkImg').animate({
        "top": "-81px"
    }, 1000);
    baseCookieName = "rwbookmark";
    var exdate = new Date();
    var expiredays = "1";
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
    //use of arbritary stop point so no endless loop occurs
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        var curName = baseCookieName + i;
        if (document.cookie.indexOf(curName) < 0) {
            document.cookie = curName + "=" + escape(window.location.href) + "[#]contentid=" + document.getElementById("inputContentID").value + "[#]title=" + GetPageTitle() + ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString() + ";path=/;domain=parlourdc.com;";
            break;
        }
    }
    var link = document.getElementById('BookmarkLink');
    link.onclick = null;
    link.style.cursor = "default";
}

function GetPageTitle() {
    var titlefromdom = "";
    var titlefromdomarray = "";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        titlefromdom = document.title;
    });
    titlefromdomarray = titlefromdom.split("|");
    if (titlefromdomarray.length > 0) {
        titlefromdom = titlefromdomarray;
    }
    return titlefromdom;
}
```

With this being the actual link they click on via the mobile site:

```
<a href="http://parlourdc.com/?ViewFullSite=true">click here to view full site</a>
```

Any ideas what could be causing the trouble?

Comment: Have you tried capturing the click event rather than using a query string? You could set the cookie on click then set the location to your ".com".

Comment: Thanks for your response. To be honest, this is my first attempt at something like this. Could you explain in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I had mentioned in my comment above:

Start by giving the anchor tag an ID:
`<a id="fullsite" href="http://parlourdc.com">click here to view full site</a>`

The process would look like this:

1. Listen for "click" event.
2. Set your cookie.
3. Set the location to the full site URL.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('fullsite').addEventListener('click',gotoFullSite,true);

function gotoFullSite(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     setCookie("viewFullSite", true, 1);
     location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
}
```

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Put the following code on both mobile site page and desktop site page too.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
var docCookies = {
            getItem: function (sKey) {
                if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return null; }
                return unescape(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|.*;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*((?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?).*"), "$1"));
            },
            setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
                if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/.test(sKey)) { return; }
                var sExpires = "";
                if (vEnd) {
                    switch (typeof vEnd) {
                        case "number": sExpires = "; max-age=" + vEnd; break;
                        case "string": sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd; break;
                        case "object": if (vEnd.hasOwnProperty("toGMTString")) { sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toGMTString(); } break;
                    }
                }
                document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=" + escape(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
            },
            removeItem: function (sKey) {
                if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return; }
                var oExpDate = new Date();
                oExpDate.setDate(oExpDate.getDate() - 1);
                document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=; expires=" + oExpDate.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
            },
            hasItem: function (sKey) { return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie); }
        };
</script>
```

**Put the following code on Full Site**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
 { 
     if( !docCookies.getItem("isMobile") ) 
     {   
      console.log("redirection");
      docCookies.setItem("isMobile","true");  
      document.location = "http://mobile site";
     }
 }
</script>
```

**Put the following code on mobile page**

HTML Code :

```
<a href="#" onclick='redirectDesktopSite();'>
 Desktop Site
</a>
```

Java Script Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function redirectDesktopSite()
{
docCookies.setItem("isMobile","true"); 
document.location='http://desktop site';
}
</script>
```